# fanotify FAN_OPEN read vs. write access?

Tags: c, fanotify

dear linux C programmers:

in the linux fanotify facility, I know how to monitor for file opens (FAN_OPEN).  I can also learn whether the open was a 'read' or 'write' if I monitor until the close, because there is a FAN_CLOSE_WRITE and a FAN_CLOSE_NOWRITE.

I always thought that it would be at open() time that one tells POSIX whether the file is opened for read/write, so that the fanotify would let me distinguish between them at the open time, not at the close time.  I must be wrong here.

am I?  why?

/iaw

Answer (score 1):

According to `fanotify_mark(2)`, the event indicates the type of file that is being closed:

> FAN_CLOSE_WRITE
>       Create an event when a writable file is closed.
>
> FAN_CLOSE_NOWRITE
>       Create an event when a read-only file or directory is closed.

In your `fanotify_mark(2)` call, you need to express interest in `FAN_MODIFY` events. If the file is modified, you will be notified.  There does not appear to be a way to know that a file was opened with write intent.  Only when the file is actually modified will you be notified.

Comment: I know.  I was wondering why this becomes known only at file closing time, not at file opening time.